# is $A=\{v|v_i\leq v_{i+1},\forall i\in\{1,2...,n-1\}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ clopen in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

The original question is

Let $A=\{v|v_i\leq v_{i+1},\forall i\in\{1,2...,n-1\}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $A$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

**Some idea:**

**Method 1:** This is pretty straight forward by arguing every convergent sequence of functions/vectors in $A$ converges in $A$ because every convergent sequence of functions converges to the limit with property $v_i\leq v_{i+1},\forall i$. Then proceed to prove such a set is closed by contradiction under the proposed argument.

However, my second idea cannot proceed further, please help.

**Method 2:**
Trying to show $A$ is closed by verifying that $A^c=\{v|v_i> v_{i+1},\forall i\in\{1,2...,n-1\}\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open.

For all $v\in A^c$, exist some $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)\gg0$ such that $\epsilon_i>\epsilon_{i+1}$ for all $i$.

Up to here, I have a question when we are trying to construct the high dimensional open ball, is this admissible $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)\gg0$ such that $\epsilon_i>\epsilon_{i+1}$ or has to be $\epsilon_i=\epsilon_{i+1}$. If the former is admissible,  then can I argue that the sphere (closure of the open ball) is fully contained in $A^c$, hence so is its interior?

I am wobbling about this idea, if this is wrong, how do we prove $A^c$ is open by any points in the set having an open ball with some $\epsilon$-radius fully contained in $A^c$, preferably with the presence of $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n)$

**Extra question**: My gut feels $A$ is also open, is this true?

Thank you for your answer, please help.

Comment: If $A$ is clopen it is either empty or all of $R^n$

Comment: Please edit the question and make the title consistent with the body. The functions $f_i(v) = v_i-v_{i+1}$ are linear hence continuous, so the set is closed since it is the set of $v$ satisfying $f_i(v) \le 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Let $\{v^k = (v_1^k, \dots, v_n^k)\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $A$ that converges to some $a=(a_1, \dots, a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Use the fact that convergence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is equivalent to convergence of every coordinate in $\mathbb{R}$ to get that $\lim_{k\to\infty} v_i^k =a_i$ for each $i=1,2,\dots,n$. Since $v_{i}^k \leq v_{i+1}^k$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $a_{i}\leq a_{i+1}$ and so $a\in A$ and $A$ is closed.

**Method 2:**

Your expression for $A^c$ is not the correct one. The correct description is
$$A^c = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^n : \exists\, i\in [n-1] \text{ s.t. } v_i > v_{i+1}\}$$

Now consider $a = (a_1, \dots, a_n) \in A^c$ and let $j$ be such that $a_{j} > a_{j+1}$. Denote $\delta = a_j - a_{j+1} > 0$. Next, consider the ball $B(a, \delta/4)$. We will show that this ball is contained entirely in $A^c$. Let $z\in B(a, \delta/4)$. It is convenient to write $z=a+u$ for some $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $\|u\|_2 < \delta / 4$. Then $|u_i| < \delta/4$ for each $i=1,2,\dots,n$ and
$$z_j - z_{j+1} = (a_j + u_j) - (a_{j+1}+u_{j+1}) = \delta + u_j-u_{j+1} > \delta - \delta/4 -\delta/4 =\delta/2>0$$
thus showing that $z\in A^c$. Since $z$ was arbitrary, $B(a, \delta/4) \subseteq A^c$ and $A^c$ is open.

**Extra question:**

$A$ is not open. An elementary way to see that, without talking about connectedness, is by showing that the ball $B(\mathbf{0}, \varepsilon)$ is not contained in $A$ no matter the choice of $\varepsilon > 0$. For example, $(\varepsilon/2,0,\dots, 0) \in B(\mathbf{0}, \varepsilon)$ but $(\varepsilon/2,0,\dots, 0)\notin A$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That's exactly what I want, but I think you may have some typo in **Method 2**

Comment: @LJNG Where? I can't see it.

Comment: Is that suppose to be $z_j-z_{j-1}=(a_j+u_j)−(a_{j+1}+u_{j+1})$

Comment: @LJNG Oh yeah you're right. Thanks, fixed!

Comment: and one more thing I want to clarify is that $\delta+u_j-u_{j+1}>\delta-\frac{\delta}{4}-\frac{\delta}{4}$ because we consider extreme case where $u_j$ is negative but $u_{j+1}$ is positive ?

Comment: @LJNG That is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $$(v_1, \dots, v_n)\mapsto \min_{1\le j \le n-1}(v_{j+1}-v_j) $$ Then $f$ is evidently continuous. Your set $A=f^{-1}([0,\infty))$. This is closed as continuous preimage of closed sets is closed.

In your second idea, the complement of $A$ is incorrect.
$$A^c=\{v | v_{i+1}<v_i, \text{ for some } 1\le i\le n-1\}$$